# Deleting duplicate word from a string file

Tags: java, string, sorting, try-catch

I'm trying to sort strings from a file using merge sort and insertion sort. I've done the sorting part but I'm stuck on the part where I have to remove all the duplicated words. In a nutshell I have to print the execution time it takes from merge and insertion sort to sort the string from a file while it removes duplicated words.

FRANKENSTEIN

MARY

WOLLSTONECRAFT

SHELLEY

LETTER

1

TO

This is what the txt file looks like but it contains more than 15,000 words in it. I can't figure out the part where I have to remove the duplicated words and then sorts it.

Thanks in advance

```
ergeSort pb = new ergeSort();
    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            l.add(line);

        }
        br.close();

        String[] arre = l.toArray(new String[]{});

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        (new ergeSort()).MergeSort(arre);
        removeDuplicate(arre);
        for(String h : arre){
            System.out.println(h);
        }

        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime1 = endTime - startTime;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        inSort(arre);
        removeDuplicate(arre);

        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime2 = endTime - startTime;

        System.out.println("The execution time of Merge sort after duplicated words are removed is: " + executionTime1 + "ms");
        System.out.println("The execution time of Insertion sort after duplicated words are removed is: " + executionTime2 + " ms");
        System.out.println("The number of words remaining after removal of duplicated: " + arre.length);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Incorrect File");

    }
}
public static class ergeSort {

    public static void MergeSort(String[] arr) {
        if (arr.length > 1) {
            String[] firstHalf = new String[arr.length / 2];
            System.arraycopy(arr, 0, firstHalf, 0, arr.length / 2);
            MergeSort(firstHalf);

            String[] secondHalf = new String[arr.length - arr.length / 2];
            System.arraycopy(arr, arr.length / 2, secondHalf, 0, arr.length - arr.length / 2);
            MergeSort(secondHalf);

            merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, arr);

        }
    }

    public static void merge(String[] arr1, String[] arr2, String[] temp) {

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            if (b >= arr2.length || (a < arr1.length && arr1[a].compareToIgnoreCase(arr2[b]) < 0)) {
                temp[i] = arr1[a];
                a++;
            } else {
                temp[i] = arr2[b];
                b++;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static String[] inSort(Comparable[] arr) {
    Comparable temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[j - 1]) < 0) {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = temp;

            }

        }

    }
    return (String[]) arr;
}

public static void removeDuplicate(String[] words) {
    {
        List<String> q = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (words[i] != null) {

                for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) //Inner loop for Comparison
                {

                    if (words[i].compareToIgnoreCase(words[j])) //Checking for both strings are equal
                    {
                        q.add(words[i]);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: why not use TreeSet ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: Use some kind of `Set`, read the file and then save it, guaranteed to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Replace List with [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and then get String array without duplicated string.
Set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements.

```
ergeSort pb = new ergeSort();
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        s.add(line);
    }
    br.close();
    String[] arre = s.toArray(new String[]{});
    //...
}
// ...
```